# How to manually update Openshift 3's container?

Tags: git, openshift

Openshift 3 would ask me to include a git link when I create the project, and create a container automatically. When I update my code to the git repo, and redeploy the container, however, the container stays the same...

Besides using web hook, is there a way to update openshift 3's container? I like to do it manually, meaning only update when I request...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If building from a Git repository, you can run `oc start-build`.

Comment: error: Must pass a name of a build config or specify build name with '--from-build' flag

Comment: `oc start-build default`
Unable to connect to the server: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority

Comment: As it says, pass the name of the build configuration. I couldn't know what it is. Use ``oc get bc`` if you don't. It usually would be same as your application resource names. The name ``default`` doesn't look right if you are trying to using the project name of the default project. You should avoid working in the default project.

Comment: As to certificate issues, are you even logged into the OpenShift cluster from the command line. Perhaps refresh what you need to do by doing https://learn.openshift.com/introduction/cluster-access/

Comment: `oc get bc` Error from server (Forbidden): User "xxx" cannot list buildconfigs in project "xxx"

Comment: `oc start-build xxx` Error from server (Forbidden): User "xxx" cannot create buildconfigs/instantiate in project "xxx"

Comment: The user you are logged in as from the command line cannot access the project. What user was the project originally created by? Has the user you are using from the command line been added as a collaborator on the project? That learn.openshift.com teaching scenario talks about adding collaborators and how to look to see who has access.

Comment: I am the original creator and the only user on this project.

Comment: Is this your own OpenShift cluster you have set up, or are you using OpenShift Online?

Comment: The solution is to do a `oc login` each time before `oc start-build xxx`, this might be a bug...

Comment: When you do an ``oc login``, an access token should be cached in a file in the ``~/.kube`` directory. That token would generally be valid for 24 hours from the point it was first issued, although how long it is active can be overridden in the OpenShift master configuration. As long as you are within the expiry period of the token, you should not need to log in again. As I asked before, is this your own cluster? Is there a chance whoever set the cluster up overrode default 24 hours and made it a lot less.

Comment: If you are on starter-us-east-1 cluster, I would suggest going to https://api.starter-us-east-1.openshift.com/oauth/token/request, login as necessary and request a new token so you know it is a fresh token. Login with that from the command line using the command given and see how long that lasts before it expires and you get a message from ``oc`` to login again. IOW, after login, keep issuing commands to ensure not being forced to login straight away. If it only lasts for a single command then yes there would be something wrong, but would be surprised if it is.